# How to determine the list of choices in a django form?

Tags: python, django

When I try to run the server I get an error that says unexpected keyword argument 'choices'

```
COMMUNE_CHOICES=[
    ('GOMBE','GOMBE'),
    ('BARUMBU','BARUMBU'),
    ('KINSHASA','KINSHASA'),
    ('LINGWALA','LINGWALA'),
    ('BANDALUNGUA','BANDALUNGUA'),
    ('MAKALA','MAKALA'),
    ('NGIRI NGIRI','NGIRI NGIRI'),
    ('KASA VUBU','KASA VUBU'),
    ('KALAMU','KALAMU'),
    ('LEMBA','LEMBA'),
    ('MATETE','MATETE'),
    ('NGABA','NGABA'),
    ('LIMETE','LIMETE'),
    ('MALUKU','MALUKU'),
    ('NSELE','NSELE'),
    ('MASINA','MASINA'),
    ('NDJILI','NDJILI'),
    ('KIMBANSEKE','KIMBANSEKE'),
    ('KISENSO','KISENSO'),
    ('NGALIEMA','NGALIEMA'),
    ('MONT NGAFULA','MONT NGAFULA'),
    ('KITAMBO','KITAMBO'),
    ('SELEMBAO','SELEMBAO'),
    ('BUMBU','BUMBU'),
]

TYPE_SERVICE=[
        ('Transport de fonds','Transport de fonds'),
        ('Comptage et conditionnement de fonds','Comptage et conditionnement de fonds'),
        ('Conditionnement comptage et transport de fonds','Conditionnement - comptage et transport de fonds')
]

TYPE_SERVICE_MENSUEL=[

        ('Conditionnement comptage et transport de fonds','Conditionnement - comptage et transport de fonds')
]

TYPE_FACTURATION=[
('Offre ponctuelle','Offre ponctuelle'),
('Offre mensuelle','Offre mensuelle')
]

ANNEES_EXPERIENCE = (
        ('1 À 5 ANS','1 À 5 ANS'),
        ('6 À 10 ANS','6 À 10 ANS'),
        ('11 À 15 ANS','11 À 15 ANS'),
        ('16 À 20 ANS','16 À 20 ANS'),
        ('PLUS DE 20 ANS','PLUS DE 20 ANS'),
    )

MULTINATIONAL = (
        ('OUI','OUI'),
        ('NON','NON'),
    )

class EscorteForm(forms.Form):
    montant_dollars = forms.IntegerField(label='Montant en dollars', min_value=0)   
    montant_franc = forms.IntegerField(label='Montant en franc congolais', min_value=0)

    taux_jour = forms.IntegerField(label='Taux du jour', min_value=920) 

    zone = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=COMMUNE_CHOICES, widget=forms.SelectMultiple())
    type_service = forms.ChoiceField(choices=TYPE_SERVICE, widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'check_type_service',}))

    multinational = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MULTINATIONAL, widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'check_type_service',}))
    annees_experience = forms.CharField(choices=ANNEES_EXPERIENCE )
```

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'choices'

Comment: Only FormFields with `Choice` in their names have choices.

Comment: CharField choice is only for model fields, not for forms fields

Comment: You should use `forms.ChoiceField(choices=ANNEES_EXPERIENCE )` instead of `forms.CharField(choices=ANNEES_EXPERIENCE )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**`CharField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField) has indeed no `choices`, this is a *form* field, so it does not deal with how you represent data in the *database*.

You perhaps want to use a [**`ChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField), and use as *widget* (the element in the HTML form that is used to talk to the user), by using [**`django-easy-select2`** [PyPi]](https://pypi.org/project/django-easy-select2/). You can install it in your virtual environment with:

```
$ pip install django-easy-select2
```

We can then use the `Select2` widget:

```
from easy_select2.widgets import Select2

class EscorteForm(forms.Form):
    montant_dollars = forms.IntegerField(label='Montant en dollars', min_value=0)   
    montant_franc = forms.IntegerField(label='Montant en franc congolais', min_value=0)
    taux_jour = forms.IntegerField(label='Taux du jour', min_value=920) 
    zone = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=COMMUNE_CHOICES, widget=forms.SelectMultiple())
    type_service = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=TYPE_SERVICE,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'check_type_service',})
    )
    multinational = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=MULTINATIONAL,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'check_type_service',})
    )
    annees_experience = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=ANNEES_EXPERIENCE,
        widget=Select2()
    )
```